# make "z" toggle between textured mode and wireframe?

Tags: 3d-view

Is it possible to make the keyboard button toggle between wireframe and textured 
instead of wireframe and solid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sure is. Just go to Blender's preferences in the Input tab. Search by key-binding: "z". In the 3D View section you will find three "Context Toggle Values" shortcuts, one being assigned to the z key only (no modifier keys). Expand this and change the value of "SOLID" to "TEXTURED".

[image: Blender keyboard configuration so that Z toggles Viewport Shading between Textured and Wireframe views]

There is a small yet notable inconsistency in labeling that, in the UI it is listed as "Texture" yet its value name is "TEXTURED" with a D on the end.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that one can already activate "Textured" mode by pressing the key combination <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, and change this back to wireframe by pressing the <kbd>Z</kbd> key. <kbd>SHFT</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> activates "rendered" mode, and it, too, is canceled by pressing the <kbd>Z</kbd> key.

But to answer the question, yes. The key bindings can be reassigned by changing the bindings in:

User Preferences > Input > 3D View > Context toggle values.